# Wait for Cloud Function to be finished

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is there any way to wait for a Cloud Function, that was triggered by a Firestore document write, to finish?

Context:

My app has groups. Owners can invite other users to a group via an invite code. Users can write themselves as member of a group if they have the right invite code. They do this by writing the `groups/{groupId}/members/{userId}` document that contains their profile info.

To make reading more efficient, this info is copied to array `members` in the `groups/{groupId}` document by a Cloud Function.

The Cloud Function that does that is triggered by the document write. It is usually finished after a couple of seconds, but there's no predictable execution time and it might take a bit longer if it is a cold start.

After the user has joined the group, I forward them to the groups view in my app which reads the group document. In order for the view to render correctly, the membership info needs to be available. So I would like to forward AFTER the Cloud Function has finished.

I found no way to track the execution of a Cloud Function that was triggered by a Firestore document write.

A fellow developer recommended to just poll the `groups/{groupId}` document until the info is written and then proceed but this doesn't seem like a clean solution to me.

Any ideas how this could be done better?

Is it possible to get a promise that resolves after the Cloud Function has finished? Is there a way to combine a Firestore document write and a Cloud Function execution into one transaction?

Comment: You can do slightly better than polling by [listening for changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This seemed like a good idea at first but when I tried it, I came across the issue, that the user is only allowed to read from `groups/{groupId}` AFTER the cloud function has written their membership into that doc. So listening to snapshot changes will fail because it will start BEFORE that was done. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you can't listen to `groups/{groupId}`, consider listening for collection changes to a collection called `users/{userId}/activityfeed` (set the query limit to 1-3). Then in your Cloud Function, batch write to both `groups/{groupId}` and `users/{userId}/activityfeed/{docId}`. To get a document ID to use in the write, call just `document(activityFeedColRef)` when building the reference and it will auto-generate an ID for you. This has the added benefit of giving your users a sort of history to look back on if they want to look back to find an old group/post.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I went with different approaches for different scenarios. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the hints, I came up with the following ways to deal with the problem. The approach depends on if/when the user is allowed to read a document:

A) User is member and leaves the group > at the start of the transaction they are allowed to read the group > the moment they can't read anymore confirms that the membership was successfully revoked:

```js
async function leaveGroup (groupId) {
  await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'groups', groupId, 'members', auth.currentUser.uid))

  // Cloud Function removes the membership info
  // from the group doc...

  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    const unsubscribeFromSnapshot = onSnapshot(
      doc(db, 'groups', groupId),
      () => { }, // success callback
      () => { // error callback
        // membership info is not in the group anymore
        //   > user can't read the doc anymore
        //     > transaction was successful
        // read access was revoked > transaction was successful:
        unsubscribeFromSnapshot()
        resolve()
      }
    )
  })
}
```

B) User is not a member and wants to join the group > at the start of the transaction they are allowed to read the group > the moment they can read the group confirms that the membership was successfully confirmed (this is a simplified version that does not check the invite code):

```js
async function joinGroup (groupId) {
  try {
    await setDoc(
      doc(db, 'groups', groupId, 'members', auth.currentUser.uid),
      {
        userId: auth.currentUser.uid,
        userDisplayName: auth.currentUser.displayName
      }
    )

    // Cloud Function adds the membership
    // information to the group doc ...

    await new Promise((resolve) => {
      let maxRetries = 10
      const interval = setInterval(async () => {
      try {
        const docSnap = await getDoc(doc(db, 'groups', groupId))
        if (docSnap.data().members.includes(auth.currentUser.uid)) {
          // membership info is in the group doc
          //   > transaction was successful
          clearInterval(interval)
          resolve()                
        }
      } catch (error) {
        if (maxRetries < 1) {
          clearInterval(interval)
        }
      }
      maxRetries--
    }, 2000)
  })
}
```

Note: I went with polling here, but similar to what @samthecodingman suggested, another solution could be that the Cloud Function confirms the membership by writing back to the `members` document (which the user can always read) and you listen to snapshot changes on this document.

C) Most straightforward way: someone else (the group owner) removes a member from the group > they have read access through the whole transaction > directly listen to snapshot changes:

```js
async function endMembership (groupId, userId) {

  await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'groups', groupId, 'members', userId))
    
  // Cloud Function removes the membership info
  // from the group doc...
    
  await new Promise((resolve) => {
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(doc(db, 'groups', groupId), (doc) => {
      if (!doc.data().members.includes(userId)) {
        // membership info is not in the group doc anymore
        //   > transaction was successful
        unsubscribe()
        resolve()
      }
    })
  })
}
```

In any case you should do proper error handling that covers other causes. I left them out to demonstrate how to use the error handlers when waiting for gaining/loosing read access.